# Android Developing.... newbie about app structure

Tags: java, android, android-layout, mobile

I am implementing an Android App. 
The user will choose a specific parameter called distance between:

```
1- kilometers;
2- miles.
```

So the app will save this response for future use of it.

How can I implement it?
Have I to create a raw resources or I have to use strings.xml?
Can you explain me the correct structure in this cases?

Comment: Please show some effort on your side..

Comment: you are not obliged to answer if you do not want help me.

Comment: @michele, I don't believe Niek is trying to be rude to you. It's just that Stack Overflow's community isn't too fond of answering questions that could be answered by a google search, at least without showing something you've done to try to figure it out. Don't take offense to it; the point is to improve the community.

Comment: But to get to your question: What do you mean by "choose a specific parameter"?

Comment: That's pretty cheeky. He says what it's all about on this platform. It's not about solving your problems but helping you to solve them yourself. Maybe someone will reply but I think you should rethink your attitude. Why should someone help you if you don't even try youself? You will find all information you need in [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Comment: It's easy to dump an idea/problem on SO and wait for the ready made apps. But that's not how it works. By showing you've tried to solve your problem yourself, people get interested in it and will try to _help_ _you_ solve your problem. But if you don't care enough, we don't care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) to save it.

Quote:

> The SharedPreferences class provides a general framework that allows
>   you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data
>   types. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data:
>   booleans, floats, ints, longs, and strings. This data will persist
>   across user sessions (even if your application is killed).
>
> To get a SharedPreferences object for your application, use one of two
>   methods:
>
> getSharedPreferences() - Use this if you need multiple preferences
>   files identified by name, which you specify with the first parameter.
>   getPreferences() - Use this if you need only one preferences file for
>   your Activity. Because this will be the only preferences file for your
>   Activity, you don't supply a name. To write values:
>
> Call edit() to get a SharedPreferences.Editor. Add values with methods
>   such as putBoolean() and putString(). Commit the new values with
>   commit() To read values, use SharedPreferences methods such as
>   getBoolean() and getString().

Here is an example that saves a preference for silent keypress mode in a calculator:

```
public class Calc extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
       super.onCreate(state);
       . . .

       // Restore preferences
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
       setSilent(silent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();

      // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
      // All objects are from android.context.Context
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for misunderstanding.
How can I do if I want that this values persistant? The solution is to creat an xml resource and parse it? 
Can I modify res/strings values from code?

Thank you again.